# Ruby multithreading each thread is slow

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I was trying to use multithreading on processing a huge array of data, but it did not improve the performance at all. I tried to explore the issue, and it turned out each thread is taking approximately the same time as running the task without threading.

Following is a simplified version I ran on `irb`.

```
arr = (0...1000000000).to_a and 1  # just to prevent irb from printing arr
>> 1

lambda { from = Time.now; arr.each{}; Time.now - from }.call
>> 58.062952

arr.each_slice((arr.size / 8.0).round).to_a.map{|arrr| Thread.new{ lambda { from = Time.now; arrr.each{}; Time.now - from }.call }}.map(&:join).map(&:value)
>> [56.541044, 46.74521, 47.887555, 49.059258, 55.008338, 55.687892, 55.997382, 55.404157]
```

As you can see, each thread took uncannily similar time as task without threading.

Notice that these times are measured for the task itself inside each thread, so it has nothing to do with communication overhead.

I tested with other size of arrays, and the results were similar - no significant difference to task without threading.

I am very puzzled. I would appreciate to learn why this is happening.

Comment: Try in JRuby, you'll likely notice improvements.

Comment: In MRI, only one ruby thread can run at any given time. It's called Global VM Lock (GVL)

Comment: Did you consider that `arr = (0...1000000000).to_a` places a huge array into your memory and your computer might need to swap a lot to handle it? Furthermore, `arr.each_slice(...).to_a` will at least duplicate the memory usage again.

Comment: @spickermann I did not because as long as I could see difference between multithreads and non-multithreads it was fine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did not know about GVL. I'll read about it. :)  Does it mean that multithreading is totally not possible in MRI? That sounds very limiting.

Comment: @user3458580: you can do I/O (to some extent) in parallel. But generally yes, multithreading in mri is seriously crippled.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your example by using [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel)

1. Install gem by running `gem install parallel` in terminal
2. Run `irb`:

   ```
   irb(main):006:0> require 'parallel'
   => true
   irb(main):001:0> arr = (0...100000000).to_a and 1
   => 1
   irb(main):002:0> lambda { from = Time.now; arr.each{}; Time.now - from }.call
   => 7.424087

   irb(main):009:0> arr.each_slice((arr.size / 8.0).round).to_a.map{|arrr| Thread.new{ lambda { from = Time.now; arrr.each{}; Time.now - from }.call }}.map(&:join).map(&:value)
   => [4.425176, 3.593438, 4.000537, 4.039098, 3.817529, 3.743535, 3.683716, 3.6868]

   irb(main):008:0> Parallel.map(arr.each_slice((arr.size / 8.0).round).to_a, in_threads: 4) { |arrr| from = Time.now; arrr.each{}; Time.now - from }
   => [2.364945, 2.365872, 2.358072, 2.469698, 2.396479, 2.283937, 2.154116, 1.910335]

   irb(main):008:0> Parallel.map(arr.each_slice((arr.size / 8.0).round).to_a, in_processes: 4) { |arrr| from = Time.now; arrr.each{}; Time.now - from }
   => [1.45764, 1.478868, 1.475091, 1.470171, 1.707919, 1.728389, 1.735843, 1.72616]
   ```